# how to distinguish methods

Tags: c#

```
using System;
interface one
{

    void getdata();

}
interface two : one
{

  new void getdata();
     void showdata();
}
class intefacehierarchy:two,one
{

    string name;

    public void getdata()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("ok tell me your name");
    }

    public void getdata()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public void showdata()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("hello mr. {0}", name));

    }

}
```

Comment: You're supposed to ask a question, not just post a piece of code... how are we supposed to guess what you want?

Comment: **What** is the question??!?!?!?

Comment: This won't compile. In C# a class's methods must all have different signatures.

Answer (score 3):

OK, that's just a guess since you didn't really ask a question, but you can use *explicit interface implementation*:

```
class intefacehierarchy:two,one
{

    string name;

    // implements two.getdata
    public void getdata()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("ok tell me your name");
    }

    // implements one.getdata explicitly
    void one.getdata()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // implements two.showdata
    public void showdata()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("hello mr. {0}", name));

    }

}
```